# CSS to make table 100% of max-width

Tags: css, html-table, width, html-email

Given the following for an email template:

```
<style>
  @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans");
</style>

<div style="width:100%; background:#F2F2F2">
  <table style="padding: 25px; margin: 0 auto; font-family:'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';">
    <tr align="center" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
      <td>
        <table style="border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color: #c3d2d9;" cellspacing="0">
          <tr style="background-color: white;">
            <td style="width: 700px; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; color: #000000;">
              <p>Some content here</p>
              <span style="font-weight: bold;">My Signature</span><br/>
              My Title<br/>
              My Company<br/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The table will be exactly 700px wide is what is needed. However, because its entirely fixed width, it can't resize on devices with less than 700px width. But if I modify the td element to this:

```
<td style="max-width: 700px; width: 90%; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; color: #000000;">
   <p>Some content here</p>
   <span style="font-weight: bold;">My Signature</span><br/>
   My Title<br/>
   My Company<br/>
</td>
```

Then the table is only ~100px wide.

How would I reorder the CSS to make it so that the table is 700px but resizes as the viewport grows smaller?

Comment: Give `width: 90%` to the first table, `width: 100%` to the second table and also try not to use inline styling..

Comment: I think he has to inline style because it is for an email template

Comment: It's important to inline styles when working with HTML email unless you don't want to support Gmail, which ignores the style tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj9Gy/1/)**

**css**

```
table{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: @Noah - This too works if you need fixed width you may want to change <div style="width:100%; background:#F2F2F2"> to <div style="width:700px; background:#F2F2F2">

Answer (score 41):

You need to use:

```css
table{
   width:100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Pablocattaneo/ov1g4ky5/4/)

Comment: That's cool, but what if we wanted a table where the columns didn't have identical widths with their siblings?

Answer (score 7):

I have a very well working solution for tables of `max-width: 100%`.
Just use `word-break: break-all;` for the table cells (except heading cells) to break all long text into several lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table {
  max-width: 100%; 
}
table td {
  word-break: break-all;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th><strong>Input</strong></th>
    <th><strong>Output</strong></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>12b6459fc6b4cabb4b1990be1a78e4dc5fa79c3a0fe9aa9f0386d673cfb762171a4aaa363b8dac4c33e0ad23e4830888</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This will render like this (when the screen width is limited):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue it was due to that I had the bootstrap class "hidden-lg" on the table which caused it to stupidly become display: block !important;

I wonder how Bootstrap never considered to just instead do this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .hidden-lg {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

And then just leave the element whatever display it had before for other screensizes.. Perhaps it is too advanced for them to figure out..

Anyway so:

```
table {
    display: table; /* check so these really applies */
    width: 100%;
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

max-width is definitely not well supported. If you're going to use it, use it in a media query in your style tag. ios, android, and windows phone default mail all support them. (gmail and outlook mobile don't)

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/targeting/

Look at the starbucks example at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:

```
table, tbody {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `table` alone wasn't enough, the `tbody` was also needed for it to work for me.

Answer (score -3):

Use this :

```
<div style="width:700px; background:#F2F2F2">
    <table style="width:100%;padding: 25px; margin: 0 auto; font-family:'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';">
        <tr align="center" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;border-style:solid; border-width:2px; border-color: #c3d2d9;" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr style="background-color: white;">
                        <td style=" padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; color: #000000;">
                            <p>Some content here</p>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;">My Signature</span><br/>
                            My Title<br/>
                            My Company<br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```